# How to get full classname with xpathquery?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, html-parsing, domdocument, classname

I'm parsing through a HTML document and I need a class name of a div. I know a part of the class name (that never changes) but I need the full class name.

Here's the code I use:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://some_website.com');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$classname_of_the_div=$xpath->query('//div[@class="part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes"]');
```

When I `var_dump()` the `$classname_of_the_div` and `$classname_of_the_div->item(0)` the result is:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } 
NULL
```

I know that `$classname_of_the_div=$xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@class="part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes"])');` gives me the content of the div but how do I get the full class name?

P.S.: The part of the classname is separated from the rest of the class name by white spaces, so it's not really a part of the class. The div has just several classes.

Comment: By saying you only know a part of the class name, do you mean you only know a part of the `class` attribute value for this particular `div`?

Comment: I mean the div has several class names like <div class="class1 class2 class3"> - I want to select it by "class2" for example and receive the full class string including "class1 class2 class3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean the div has several class names like  - I want to select it by "class2" for example and receive the
>   full class string including "class1 class2 class3"

Then, an XPath expression like

```
//div[@class="part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes"]
```

will never yield a result, save for the situation that a particular `div` element only has one class, that is, the one "that never changes". That's because the XPath expression above means:

> Select `div` elements that have a `class` attribute whose string value
>   *exactly* corresponds to "part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes".

---

But imagine the following situation:

```
<div class="part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes other_class1 other_class2"/>
```

Then, you would need to change the expression to:

```
//div[contains(@class,'part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes')]/@class
```

The expression means:

> Look for `div` elements that have a `class` attribute whose string
>   value *contains* the string
>   "part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes" and return the attribute
>   value.

Comment: Indeed, that did the job! Thank you very much! Using $classname_of_the_div=$xpath->query('//div[contains(@class, "part_of_the_class_name_that_never_changes")]/@class'); and $classname_of_the_div->item(0)->value gave back the String I needed